# Dynamically modify content added to table via javascript

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, table

What I want to do is quite straightforward, but I can't figure it out. Let's say you have this variable defined in your global scope of your script:

`var contentOfRow = "<tr><td>hello</td></tr>";`

Then, you have a HTML table, on top of which you have a +ADD button. On this button, you specify `onlick="addRow(contentOfRow)"`, such that, on each click on the +ADD button, a new row is added onto the HTML table, with its content equal to the value of `contentOfRow`. That's where I am, all of this works.

What's not working is that, with each click on the +ADD button, I want to modify the value of `contentOfRow` (so inside the addRow(contentOfRow) function), such that subsequent clicks on the +ADD button simply add the programmatically updated content onto the HTML table, if clicked again. Given that the `var` keyword was used, I simply reassigned the value of the variable like so:

`contentOfRow = "<tr><td>newContent</td></tr>";`

Inside the addRow(contentOfRow) function. Yet, if I click on the +ADD button, no matter how many times, it always adds the original row with the content `<tr><td>hello</td></tr>`onto the table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; if you actually store the rowContent as an object property

`var content.row1 = "<tr><td>hello</td></tr>";`

And then redefine that propertie's value inside the `addRow()`function, now not taking any parameters anymore, via simply:

`content.row1 = "<tr><td>newContent</td></tr>";`

everything works, and subsequent clicks on the +ADD button add "newContent" rows onto the HTML table.